# Fetch React Native unexpected token

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a simple app the retrieves data from a facebook demo api and displays them with react native.

This is my code (for index.android.js) :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text , View } from 'react-native';

class AwesomeProject extends Component{


  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    }

  };

  componentWillMount(){
      this.getMoviesFromApi().then((res) => {
          movies: res.movies;
      });
  }



   async function getMoviesFromApi() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      return responseJson.movies;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }



  render() {

      return(
          <Text>
            {this.state.movies}
          </Text>
        );

  }

}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject',() => AwesomeProject);
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

```
Unexcepted token, excpected ( (28:18) index.android.js:23:18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code.
1. Use `setState` to update movies property.

```
  this.getMoviesFromApi().then((res) => {
    this.setState({
      movies: res
    });
  });
```

2. `async function getMoviesFromApi()` should be just `async getMoviesFromApi()`
3. In `render` function, wrap `Text` inside `View` and loop through movies array. Example -

```
  return(
    <View>
      {this.state.movies.map(m => (
        <Text key={m.title}> {m.title} </Text>))}
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: thank you sir. Can you please tell me where to find some good tutorials to get started with react native? I'm really interested in the technology, but I'm a total beginner with react @vinayr

Comment: This tutorial is pretty good https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial